# Did Jesus allow his disciples to keep a staff on their journey?

Tags: matthew, contradiction, mark, bible-versions

Is there some here to clarify me why this question has tow opposite different answers in Bible , such that the question is :

Did Jesus allow his disciples to keep a staff on their journey?

**The first answer in Mark**

(a) Yes (Mark 6:8).

**The second Answer in Luke**

(b) No (Matthew 10:9; Luke 9:3)

Thanks for in Advanced

Comment: Do you mean Matt 10:10?

Comment: The only difference between Mark and the others is the presence of an extra *ei*, in whose absence the text's meaning would be identical with that of the other two. Basically, *me* means *no/not/nor*, and *ei me* means *if not (for)* or *except (for)*.

Answer (score 2):

The "staff" in Matt 10:10 must be understood by what has been said in relation to the "spares" of other travelling provisions - it was not to be an extra staff.  Thus, the travelling evangelists were allowed one staff but not two. This then agree with Mark 6:8 for just one staff (not two).

Ellicott agrees in his comment in Matt 10:10

> Neither shoes, nor yet staves.--The apparent contradiction between
>   these words and St. Mark's "nothing except a staff only," "be shod
>   with sandals," is explained by what has been said above. They were to
>   have none of the reserved comforts of common travellers, no second
>   staff in case the first should break, no second pair of shoes in which
>   to rest the worn and weary feet.