# Is the article at Titus 2:13 anaphoric? If not, what grammatical reasons deny it is?

Tags: greek, grammar, titus

Is the article at **Titus 2:13** anaphoric? If not, what grammatical reasons deny it is?

**Note**:  Keep in mind that Wallace says "Most individualizing articles will be anaphoric" [**a**]  Also anaphoric is not mutually exclusive with other designations.

The answer to this question must be grammatical, not merely mention grammatical terms. It should also directly address the Greek anaphoric article. **Titus 2:13** is a text which some interpret with Sharp’s rule.   This question does not discuss Sharp's rule as there is already a question for that [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/47369/33125).

The articular “*God*” at **Titus 2:13**  has a potential antecedent in the classic anarthrous “*first mention*,” in **Titus 1:1-4** which explicitly identifies God as the Father. [**a**]

> **Titus 1-1-4** Paul, a servant of **[anarthrous] God**, and an apostle of Jesus Christ, according to the faith of **[anarthrous] God’s** elect, and the knowledge of the truth which is according to godliness,  2 in hope of eternal life, which God, who cannot lie, promised before times eternal;  3 but in his own seasons manifested his word in the message, wherewith I was intrusted according to the commandment of God our Saviour;  4 to Titus, my true child after a common faith: Grace and peace from **God the Father** and Christ Jesus our Saviour

Is the article at **Titus 2:13** anaphoric? If not, what grammatical reasons deny it is?

---

[**a**] Practically speaking, labeling an article as anaphoric requires that it have been introduced at most in the same book, preferably in a context not too far removed…Most individualizing articles will be anaphoric in a very broad sense. (**Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics, Wallace 1996, p 218**).

Comment: @Dottard See footnote [a]

Comment: @Dottard Are you asking that I answer the question?   Titus 1:4 meets the requirement

Comment: @Dottard  I want to see if there is a grammatical rebuttal to my analysis. I made sure Wallace was notified and saw him upload it from academia.   Ideally someone he coaches can provide his viewpoint.   He told  Nigel he might assign a student, but I'm not sure if it is for this or Sharp's.

Comment: Whatever may, or may not, be true of language or grammar, whatever its rules and its means, this one true thing must be held in mind, in order to understand any scripture that exists : I and my Father are One. If 'God' - in any particular place - means 'Father' : then it is still true (in that particular place) that _I and my Father are One_.

Comment: That this site has extremely capable and well qualified exegetes is unquestioned.  But that is the point - none, except the notable vociferous very few try to justify their theological position with such an incessant parade overtly theological questions couched in terms that begs or assumes the OP's patently desired result, albeit one text at a time!  I suspect that is why many refrain.

Comment: Other than theology (i.e God = Father) why do you determine it is anaphoric to θεοῦ πατρὸς in 1:4 and not τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ of 1:3 or θεὸς πρὸ χρόνων αἰωνίων of 1:2 or ἐκλεκτῶν θεοῦ of 1:1?

Comment: Do you believe all articles are anaphoric?

Comment: Titus 2:13 seems very far away from 1:1-4; perhaps it would help the discussion if you would present at least one clear example exhibiting a comparable distance, so as to help bridge the gap between the theoretically-possible and the relatively-plausible.

Comment: Aren't there other ways individualizing articles are used, eg. kataphoric?

Comment: Citing from Wallace p. 344-5 2 Cor 8:18, 1 Tim 1:15, John 17:26, Phil 1:29. And kataphoric is just one of the different type of individualizing - contrary to you position all individualizing article are anaphoric.

Comment: @ThomasPearne: What paper (of yours) are you referring to ? Or perhaps you meant the one by Wallace ?

Comment: @ThomasPearne: As usual, your logic fallacies are quite easily seen from the get go. Pronouns might indeed refer to a noun, but not necessarily *back* to it. (Otherwise, one might also ask to what **previous** noun the first articles of Genesis 1:1 point **back** to).

Comment: Rom9:5 is most definitely not the Father. Two, you have no Scriptural precedent to deny the divinity of Christ as being part of the echad God. On the contrary the OT points the other way entirely, NUMEROUS times over. As for your other verses you’re assuming (without Scriptural precedent) that it is speaking of the Father. The whole anaphora is sleight of hand. Smoke and mirrors.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: Personally, I am rather suspicious of [Romans 9:5](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33257).

Comment: @Lucian that is a bizarre suspicion. The fact that there isn’t a pattern (to your liking), it would appear to be an inversion? If there was going to be an inversion it would be the other way around, since the first are all one way the last would have inverted to follow the pattern but it’s not. Besides the fact that God who claimed to sustain His own word and besides the fact that if Jesus were not God then His sacrifice would be insufficient for more than one substitutionary sinner. I understand to look for patterns in art, in math maybe even in poetry but a doctrinal letter?

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: An inversion does not equate Christ's non-divinity. And it is far from bizarre. Other small differences have been recorded [elsewhere](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47529).

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking us if the (articulated form of the Greek word for) *God* from **the end of one chapter** is basically a throwback to an expression used at **the beginning of the previous chapter**. At first glance, this might seem somewhat unlikely, but, in all fairness, I think you meant to ask two questions at once, only to end up being detrimentally parsimonious to oneself; thus, allow me first to rephrase your own question, so that it might make more sense, both to myself, and other readers:

> - Is the article at Titus 2:13 **ultimately** anaphoric to θεός at Titus 1:1-4 ?

Or, to unpack it even further:

> - Is the expression at Titus 2:13 a throwback to the one mentioned just verses earlier, at Titus 2:10-11 ?
> - Does the expression at Titus 2:10 reference the same entity as the similar one employed previously at Titus 1:3, and, later on, at Titus 3:4 ?
> - Are the articles at Titus 1:2-3 anaphoric to the two unarticulated forms found in the previous verse ?

To state matters plainly, you seem to have the following hermeneutic approach in mind:

> **Titus 1:3**  But hath in due times manifested his word through preaching, which is committed unto me according to the commandment of **God our Saviour**.
>
> **Titus 2:10**  Not purloining, but shewing all good fidelity; that they may adorn the doctrine of **God our Saviour** in all things.
>
> **Titus 3:4**  But after that the kindness and love of **God our Saviour** toward man appeared...

with a possible (and arguably plausible) interpretative key provided by:

> **Titus 1:4**  To Titus, mine own son after the common faith: Grace, mercy, and peace, from **God the Father** and the Lord Jesus Christ our Saviour.

<sub>**Note:** The following sentence is neither an argument used in the [OP](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/48335/33125), nor a grammatical observation. The OP is entirely grammar. **End Note.**</sub>

along with the observation that whenever the word God appears in the vicinity of Christ, it **usually** refers to the Father:

> **Titus 1:1**  ¶Paul, a servant of **God, and** an apostle of **Jesus Christ**, according to the faith of God's elect, and the acknowledging of the truth which is after godliness.
>
> **Titus 1:4**  To Titus, mine own son after the common faith: Grace, mercy, and peace, from **God the Father and** the Lord **Jesus Christ** our Saviour.

thus substantiating the proposed interpretation of:

> **Titus 2:13**  Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the great **God and** our Saviour **Jesus Christ**.

as referring to two distinct entities, rather than one. Though not impossible, let us also take a closer look at the way in which the word **Savior** is employed throughout the Epistle:

> **Titus 1:3**  But hath in due times manifested his word through preaching, which is committed unto me according to the commandment of **God our Saviour**.
>
> **Titus 1:4**  To Titus, mine own son after the common faith: Grace, mercy, and peace, from God the Father and the Lord **Jesus Christ our Saviour**.
>
> **Titus 2:10**  Not purloining, but shewing all good fidelity; that they may adorn the doctrine of **God our Saviour** in all things.
>
> **Titus 2:13**  Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the great God and **our Saviour Jesus Christ**.
>
> **Titus 3:4**  But after that the kindness and love of **God our Saviour** toward man appeared...
>
> **Titus 3:6**  Which he shed on us abundantly through **Jesus Christ our Saviour**.

<sub>**Note:** The previous examples of **"Savior"** don't employ a grammatical analysis and are merely comments on superficial similarities in the English text. If it is meant as applicable to the OP, that needs to be fixed. These phrases are discussed in the [original paper](http://drgregoryblunt.files.wordpress.com/2019/12/anaphora-v21.pdf#page14)  (See **Titus 3:6**) and applied with Greek grammar. That would be a good starting point. **End Note.**</sub>

The rhetorical mechanism employed here seems thus similar to the one used in the Prologue to John's Gospel, as well as 10:28-29, wherein the various attributes of God are portrayed as being mirrored in Christ; as such, it would not be farfetched to interpret the somewhat ambiguous expression of 2:13 (the great **God and our Saviour Jesus Christ**) as a combination of the other two (namely, **God our Saviour** and **Jesus Christ our Saviour**).

<sub>**Note:** Neither alleged "rhetoric mechanisms" or rhetoric nonsense are grammatical arguments. This should be excised from this answer. **End Note.**</sub>

Therefore, in conclusion:

> **Is** the article at Titus 2:13 anaphoric?

It **might** be.

(And please **stop** formulating your questions in such **absolute** language; i.e., don't ask whether it **is**, but rather whether it **could** be, or, alternately, **to what extent** it would be **plausible** to regard it as such).

> **If so**, what is its antecedent?

The similar phrase just three verses earlier, as already stated above.

Comment: @ThomasPearne: If the non-articulated noun *God* from the first two verses has an anaphoric article pointing at it, then that is most likely the one preceding the articulated noun *God* in the verse immediately following them. Nor can I spot any differences, in the Greek, between the use of *Soteros* in the aforementioned verses.

Comment: @ThomasPearne: **God our Savior** and **Christ our Savior** have the **same grammatical structure** in both **Greek** and English, your objections being of a **hermeneutic rather than strictly grammatical** nature. Secondly, I do **agree** with the Father as an ultimate cause, and the Son as an intermediate tool; same for creation in John. This was the meaning of my words.

Answer (score 1):

Here is every use of God in the letter to Titus:

```
1:1   θεοῦ - θεοῦ            2:1   ----                   3:1   ----
1:2   ὁ ἀψευδὴς θεὸς         2:2   ----                   3:2   ----
1:3   τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ  2:3   ----                   3:3   ----
1:4   θεοῦ πατρὸς            2:4   ----                   3:4   τοῦ σωτῆρος ἡμῶν θεοῦ
1:5   ----                   2:5   τοῦ θεοῦ               3:5   ----  
1:6   ----                   2:6   ----                   3:6   ----
1:7   θεοῦ                   2:7   ----                   3:7   ----
1:8   ----                   2:8   ----                   3:8   τῷ θεῷ
1:9   ----                   2:9   ----                   3:9   ----
1:10  ----                   2:10  τοῦ σωτῆρος ὑμῶν θεοῦ  3:10  ----
1:11  ----                   2:11  τοῦ θεοῦ σωτήριος      3:11  ----
1:12  ----                   2:12  ----                   3:12  ----
1:13  ----                   2:13  τοῦ μεγάλου θεοῦ       3:13  ----
1:14  ----                   2:14  ----                   3:14  ----
1:15  ----                   2:15  ----                   3:15  ----
1:16  θεὸν
```

If the article is necessary to point the reader back to a specific use of God, then it should be necessary for all subsequent uses. But as can be seen, even after identifying God as Father, "God" is used with and without the article. Since the reader is always able to identify God without the article (eg. θεοῦ, v. 6 and θεὸν, v. 7), the article is not need as an anaphoric device to identify God.

The conclusion the article can never be only anaphoric when used with God, is seen when Wallace's instructions for classification are followed:

> ...attempt to find the *narrowest* category to which a particular article can belong. As long as you can say "yes" to a particular semantic force, you should continue on until you get to the narrowest category for a particular article.<sup>`1`</sup>

[image]

Obviously, "God" will **always** be "well-known" and "the best of its class." Any attempt to limit the purpose of the article as simply anaphoric, is ignoring how the article is to be classified. Moreover, as the letter shows, the article is never really needed as a "pointer" to identify God, regardless of where in the letter God is found.

In addition to using the article to place a substantive in a particular category, all grammars recognize the article has special uses with multiple substantives connected by καὶ. This use must first be considered before attempting to limit the function of the article to simple identification. In other words, just as one looks for the most specific use to categorize, one looks at the entire text to see if the article has a narrower purpose beyond simple identification and classification.

In the case of Titus 2:13, the article is used with καὶ to connect multiple substantives. Here the concept of an anaphoric use is impossible, as the purpose for using the article in this construction is to point the reader **forward** to the other substantive:

> In Greek, when two nouns are connected by καὶ and the article precedes only the first noun, there is a close connection between the two. The connection always indicates at least some sort of *unity*. At a higher level, it may connote *equality*. At the highest level it may indicate *identity*.<sup>`2`</sup>

Since the purpose of the article in texts of this type is to point the reader to understand the relationship with what "lies ahead," the use of the article in this type of construction can never be anaphoric, regardless of the precise relationship between the two substantives.

---

<sub>1. Daniel B. Wallace, *Greek Grammar: Beyond the Basics An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament*, Zondervan, 1996, pp. 230-231

2. Wallace, p. 270</sub>

Comment: @ThomasPearne I disagree. You are obviously trying to limit the classification to anaphoric and obviously to deny the T-S-K-S construction. Your novel argument is the T-S-K-S construction is trumped by the "anaphoric article" with God. In the hundreds of years of examining this text, no scholar has ever made such an argument. You distort Wallace, Middleton and every scholar you cite because you pick and chose statements which are obviously not applicable to the specific text.